# Constructing AST in ANTLR version4

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, stringtemplate-4

I am developing a compiler and have already implemented lexer, parser and semantic analyzer(using listener and visitor) using ANTLR4. For code generation I am planning to generate LLVM IR using StringTemplate(ST).
To do so I am thinking of first constructing an AST and then generating the code.

My question here is do I need to construct AST?? or can I use Parse Tree?
If I need to use AST, I am not able to find any examples of manually constructing AST using visitors or listeners. Even a small grammar example will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no fundamental need to construct an AST.  In the simplest case, you can walk the parse-tree and output the IR, directly or using ST.

Where transformations are required for output as IR, the two basic approaches are to (1) analyze and annotate the parse-tree describing the necessary changes; or (2) walk the parse-tree, constructing a separate AST, and then walk and transform the AST.

For the annotation strategy, extend [ParseTreeProperty](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeProperty.java) to create context node type specific property classes. See the comment in that class for how to use.

The AST strategy is not discouraged -- it was the primary strategy used in Antlr3 -- but is essentially unsupported in Antlr4. As for why Antlr4 favors the annotation strategy, see the last few [paragraphs of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312976/antlr-4-parser-grammar/30335862#30335862).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I could output the IR by walking parse tree for simple constructs like binary operations. I am not able to handle Inheritance that well(base class function calls from derived class / function overriding). Have you seen any such projects online? An example would be of great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I know of no such projects. Perhaps best to post a new question, with illustrative details, for how to analyze and resolve the parse-tree structure suitable for output.